# ar_pose artoolkit problem

Tags: ros, ar-pose, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i'm working with [ar_pose](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose) package. When i try to run demo:

> roslaunch ar_pose demo_single.launch

the demo doesn't run correctly and see this message from terminal.

> [ERROR] [1323256898.236396302]: Client
> [/ar_pose] wants topic
> /usb_cam/camera_info to have
> datatype/md5sum
> [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214],
> but our version has
> [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f].
> Dropping connection. [ERROR]
> [1323256908.957549386,
> 1275671534.365555223]: Client [/rviz] wants topic /usb_cam/camera_info to
> have datatype/md5sum
> [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214],
> but our version has
> [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f].
> Dropping connection.Dropping connection.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12252/ar_pose-artoolkit-problem/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can solve this issue running the [rosbag fix](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#fix) command on your downloaded bag files. The program will work, but still there is going to be some issues with the markers drawing. This issue and its fix is explained [here](http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/trac/ticket/17). But have in mind that this fix is only for the demos. If you run the node with your camera, things should be ok. regards.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ar_pose` is looking at a version of the message with different fields than it expects. If the message description of sensor_msgs::CameraInfo is different between the topic and the subscriber, you will see this error. Since Rviz is having the same problem, I would guess that whatever node is publishing /usb_cam/camera_info is publishing incorrectly or is from an older version of ROS than you're using.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2